# Can't Get Angular Controller to work in MVC Layout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC app that uses the _Layout page to render a header and a sidebar in every page.  I am trying to use Angular's Accordion for the menus.  However, as soon as I try to place a controller in my _Layout page all of my angular code stops working (I have angular in the Index.cshtml which displays via RenderBody()).

Here is my _Layout page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")


    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-0.13.3.js"></script>

    <link href="~/Content/Layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="~/Scripts/app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/app/LayoutCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/app/generalsearchService.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="float-left">
                <p class="site-title">
            </div>
            <div class="float-right">
                <nav>

                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

    </header>
    <div ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="LayoutCtrl">
                    <nav class='sidebar sidebar-menu-collapsed'>
                        <a href='#' id='justify-icon'>
                            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right'>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        <ul>
                            <li class='active'>
                                <a class='expandable' href='#' title='Dashboard'>
                                    <div id="myTab" class='vertical-text collapsed-element' style="color:blue; width:300px">Expand For Menu Options
                                    </div>
                                    <span class='expanded-element'>Dashboard</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class='expandable' href='#' title='APIs'>
                                    <span class="collapsed-element"></span>
                                    <span class='expanded-element'>APIs</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class='expandable' href='#' title='Settings'>
                                    <span class="collapsed-element"></span>

                                    <span class='expanded-element'>Settings</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class='expandable' href='#' title='Account'>
                                    <span class="collapsed-element"></span>

                                    <span class='expanded-element'>Account</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <a href='#' id='logout-icon' title='Logout'>
                            <span class="collapsed-element"></span>

                            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-off'></span>
                        </a>
                    </nav>
        <nav>
            <accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
                <accordion-group is-open="status.open">
                    <accordion-heading>
                    </accordion-heading>
                </accordion-group>
            </accordion>
        </nav>

    </div>
    <div id="myBody" style="margin-top:50px; margin-left:320px; width:80%; position:absolute">
        @RenderBody()


    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            $(function () {
                var collapseMyMenu, expandMyMenu, toggleGlyphCollapse, toggleGlyphExpand, hideMenuTexts, showMenuTexts;
                expandMyMenu = function () {
                    document.getElementById('myBody').style.width = '80%';
                    document.getElementById('myBody').style.marginLeft = '320px';
                    document.getElementById('myTab').style.color = '#E6E7E8';


                    return $("nav.sidebar").removeClass("sidebar-menu-collapsed").addClass("sidebar-menu-expanded");
                };

                collapseMyMenu = function () {
                    document.getElementById('myBody').style.width = '99%';
                    document.getElementById('myBody').style.marginLeft = '70px';
                    document.getElementById('myTab').style.color = 'blue';


                    return $("nav.sidebar").removeClass("sidebar-menu-expanded").addClass("sidebar-menu-collapsed");
                };
                showMenuTexts = function () {
                    return $("nav.sidebar ul a span.expanded-element").show();
                };
                hideMenuTexts = function () {
                    return $("nav.sidebar ul a span.expanded-element").hide();
                };
                return $("#justify-icon").click(function (e) {
                    if ($(this).parent("nav.sidebar").hasClass("sidebar-menu-collapsed")) {
                        expandMyMenu();
                        showMenuTexts();
                        $(this).css({
                            color: "#000"
                        });
                    } else if ($(this).parent("nav.sidebar").hasClass("sidebar-menu-expanded")) {
                        collapseMyMenu();
                        hideMenuTexts();
                        $(this).css({
                            color: "#FFF"
                        });
                    }
                    $(this).find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-triangle-right').toggleClass('glyphicon-triangle-left');

                    return false;
                });
            });

        }).call(this);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

here is my Angular controller for the _Layout:

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('LayoutCtrl', function ($scope, generalsearchService) {
    getmenuItems();
    function getmenuItems() {
        generalsearchService.GetMenuItems()
        .success(function (data) {
            $scope.menuItems = data;
        });
    };
});
```

The Angular in my Index.cshtml page works fine until I add the above to the _Layout page.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?  I've been working on this for hours and just can't seem to figure it out.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you check your console I'm guessing you'll find the answer yourself

Comment: Sarcasm is lost on a newbie.  I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: We can't deduce much without seeing the error you're getting. Since you didn't post the error, I'm guessing you haven't checked the console. If you do look in the console, I'm guessing you'll figure it out yourself since Angular has a pretty decent error reporting. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info See the "debugging" part

Comment: Also, if I were you I'd try to get rid of that jquery, since you're alrady using angular anyways. I didn't look too deep into it but it looks like it could all be replaced with a few css classes and an angular state property (collapsed/expanded) on your scope.

Comment: Here's an example boilerplate for what looks like your entire jQuery code http://jsbin.com/xoxacajota/edit?html,js,output

Comment: The problem is not getting the accordion functionality to work, the problem is that as soon as I try to add angular to my _Layout, it causes the angular on the Index page to stop working.  The JQuery at the bottom is just to make the entire sidebar itself expand and collapse from left to right, not to accordion the menus in the sidebar.  Thanks for the debugging info.  I'll see if that helps me figure out the problem.

Comment: Yeah, the jquery suggestion has nothing to do with the error you're getting, it's a completely separate issue

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for my issue, although it is not the best solution because it will require that I put everything  in one controller.  The workaround is to put a div around everything in the body of my _Layout page(which includes the "@RenderBody" which renders my Index page) and include the ng-app and ng-controller in that div on the _Layout page.  If anyone knows of a better solution..I'm all ears.  Thanks to those who took the time to try to help thus far.

Comment: Well, you need just the one `ng-app` directive (set on the body for example so you don't need the wrapper div), but you could have multiple controllers if you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316355/multiple-controllers-with-angularjs-in-single-page-app Post a jsbin or plunkr with an MVCE if you're still having problems.