# declare one controller for each tab

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, restangular

I'm using tabs in an html page and I'm trying to declare one controller for each tab.

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="customerInfo">
        @customerList()
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="communities">
        @communityList()
</div>
```

For the first tab I declare my controller in "customerList" like this :

```
<div class="block full" ng-controller="customerCtrl">
```

and I tried the same thing with the second tab but it didn't work. Any help please.

Comment: It's hard to help with so little code here, I'd recommend creating a plnkr with what your trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, what I want to do is simple, in the first tab I have a list of customers where I want to use customerCtrl and for the second tab which contains communities list I want to use another controller : communitiesCtrl

Comment: I would look into using "controller as" to accomplish this. If you do a search for this you will find a ton of examples out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible and judging from here you can do this as simple as:

```
<body ng-app="">
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="customerInfo" ng-controller="customerListcontroller">
        @customerList()
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="communities" ng-controller="communityListcontroller">
        @communityList()
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

There are few things you might be doing wrong:

- forget to put ng-app="app" to wrap your controllers
- From the question there is a div omission. Make sure this is not the case in the code
- Not defining your controllers properly.
- Not calling the file containing the controller in the HTML file

It should be a minor fix. [You can also take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24316355/multiple-controllers-with-angularjs-in-single-page-app).